Scattered objects are too small and moved to the side
I'm using Blender for the first time and I'm following the donut tutorial by Blender Guru on YouTube. I want to distribute 4 different types of long sprinkles on my donut icing. It worked with the round sprinkles, but then I duplicated the donut and added the collection with the 4 sprinkles into the Geometry Nodes. At first, I could barely see anything, but after zooming in a lot, I saw extremely small sprinkles. I don't know why they were so small. Then I made them bigger (as you can see in the image at "Instance on points," where I set the scale to 7), but the sprinkles are not on top of the donut icing; they are slightly off to the side. I didn't have this problem with the first donut. Do you know what I did wrong or how to fix it?


Do you try to apply transformations after you moves/scaled objects ? You can also share your Blender file using https://blend-exchange.com/ for us to give it a try.

Use Reset Children on the Collection Info node.

Hi, thanks for the post. This site is not a regular forum, answers should be substantial, stand on their own, and thoroughly explain the solution and required steps. One liners and short tips rarely make for a good answer. If you can, [edit] your post and provide some more details about the procedure and how it works, perhaps add a few images illustrating some steps and final result. See How to write a good answer?, otherwise it may be converted to a comment.

@DuarteFarrajotaRamos I think this is one of the times when this answer is sufficient. it the one asking the question needs more info than I'd provide, but I don't see what extra information would be needed. it's a simple question with a simple answer. there isn't much if at all I could add to this answer. and it's not a comment, so that if someone is browsing, they could see that it's answered.

I used "Reset Children", but the sprinkles are still too small. At least, they're on the donut now.

@S12345 I was addressing the issue of them being offset and not on the surface. if they are too small then just make them bigger ‍♂️. or scale them up.
